# Recursively renaming directory/file structures on a local file system

Tags: python

I'm trying to define `arg1` outside of `rename()` and it does not work since `dirs` is not defined. If I use `rename("dirs", False)`, the function does not work.

Any idea?

```
# Defining the function that renames the target
def rename(arg1, arg2):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(           # Listing
        path, topdown=arg2):
        for i, name in enumerate(arg1):
            output = name.replace(pattern, "")  # Taking out pattern
            if output != name:
                os.rename(                      # Renaming
                    os.path.join(root, name),
                    os.path.join(root, output))
            else:
                pass

# Run
rename(dirs, False)
```

Here's the whole program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This program batch renames files or folders by taking out a certain pattern

import os
import subprocess

import re

# Defining the function that renames the target
def rename(arg1, arg2):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(           # Listing
        path, topdown=arg2):
        for i, name in enumerate(arg1):
            output = name.replace(pattern, "")  # Taking out pattern
            if output != name:
                os.rename(                      # Renaming
                    os.path.join(root, name),
                    os.path.join(root, output))
            else:
                pass


# User chooses between file and folder
print "What do you want to rename?"
print "1 - Folders\n2 - Files\n"
valid = False
while not valid:
    try:
        choice = int(raw_input("Enter number here: "))
        if choice > 2:
            print "Please enter a valid number\n"
            valid = False
        else:
            valid = True
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a valid number\n"
        valid = False
        choice = 3  # To have a correct value of choice

# Asking for path & pattern
if choice == 1:
    kind = "folders"
elif choice == 2:
    kind = "files"
else:
    pass
path = raw_input("What is the path to the %s?\n " % (kind))
pattern =  raw_input("What is the pattern to remove?\n ")

# CHOICE = 1
# Renaming folders
if choice == 1:
    rename(dirs, False)

# CHOICE = 2
# Renaming files
if choice == 2:
    rename(files,True)

# Success message
kind = kind.replace("f", "F")
print "%s renamed" % (kind)
```

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the directory structure you are trying to rename from and to? I suspect there is a better approach to what you're trying to do...

Comment: Is it clearer with the whole program?

Comment: Yes seeing your entire program has made the question a lot clearer. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesMills Lets say I have /Test/HHH -TEST- and /TEST/HHH -TEST-/BBB -TEST- .I want to remove -TEST- from both directory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recorrect my code in a better way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys


# the command like this: python rename dirs /your/path/name/ tst
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mode = sys.argv[1]  # dirs or files
    pathname = sys.argv[2]
    pattern = sys.argv[3]

    ndict = {'dirs': '', 'files': ''}
    topdown = {'dirs': False, 'files': True}

    for root, ndict['dirs'], ndict['files'] in os.walk(
            pathname, topdown[mode]):
        for name in enumerate(ndict[mode]):
            newname = name.replace(pattern, '')
            if newname != name:
                os.rename(
                    os.path.join(root, name),
                    os.path.join(root, newname))
```

Comment: I disagree. This is sub-optimal and not clearer as to what's going on. Re-using libraries that already implement and provide good functionality for common use-cases is better (*unless you're trying to learn how it's done*).

Comment: Your "changes" also have bugs and is untested :/ Where does ``path`` come from? This will likely throw a ``NameError``

Comment: @JamesMills Yes, you answer is very correctly, and you rewrite the whole code of the asker provide. and I only improve the "code asker provided" where need to be corrected to make the programming running. So I think I still need to learn from you, not only correct the code where is wrong, and also tidy the code in a more suitable way.

Comment: I do agree with @stupidgrass. His code indeed works, and he answered my original question. I'll still be using your code though!

Comment: *sigh* If you are **really* interested in learning to program in Python, it is generally a good idea to learn good practices. That's what I tried to provide :/

Comment: @baldurmen Thx for accept my result, and I improve my coding format now

Comment: @JamesMills Yes, you are right, and I take a little more time to improve my code format, and thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

This is better achieved as a command-line tool using the [py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py) library:

```
import sys


from py.path import local  # import local path object/class


def rename_files(root, pattern):
    """
    Iterate over all paths starting at root using ``~py.path.local.visit()``
    check if it is a file using ``~py.path.local.check(file=True)`` and
    rename it with a new basename with ``pattern`` stripped out.
    """

    for path in root.visit(rec=True):
        if path.check(file=True):
            path.rename(path.new(basename=path.basename.replace(pattern, "")))


def rename_dirs(root, pattern):
    """
    Iterate over all paths starting at root using ``~py.path.local.visit()``
    check if it is a directory using ``~py.path.local.check(dir=True)`` and
    rename it with a new basename with ``pattern`` stripped out.
    """

    for path in root.visit(rec=True):
        if path.check(dir=True):
            path.rename(path.new(basename=path.basename.replace(pattern, "")))


def main():
    """Define our main top-level entry point"""

    root = local(sys.argv[1])  # 1 to skip the program name
    pattern = sys.argv[2]

    if local(sys.argv[0]).purebasename == "renamefiles":
        rename_files(root, pattern)
    else:
        rename_dirs(root, pattern)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    Python sets ``__name__`` (a global variable) to ``__main__`` when being called
    as a script/application. e.g: Python renamefiles or ./renamefiles
    """

    main()  # Call our main function
```

**Usage:**

```
renamefiles /path/to/dir pattern
```

or:

```
renamedirs /path/to/dir pattern
```

Save this as `renamefiles` or `renamedirs`.
A common approach in UNIX is to name the script/tool `renamefiles` and symlink `renamefiles` to `renamedirs`.

**Improvement Notes:**

- Use `optparse` or `argparse` to provide Command Line Options = and a `--help`
- Make `rename_files()` and `rename_dirs()` generic and move it into a single function.
- Write documentation (*docstrings*)
- Write unit tests.

Comment: James Mills 1
baldurmen 0
Thanks mate, it's really nice (even thought my ego says "outch" :D)

Comment: @baldurmen You're welcome. I just hope this wasn't a school/university assignment and I just solved it for you :) -- I hope it will be a generally useful tool to others!

Comment: Could you please comment the above code? I'm really having trouble to find docs for this such as str.visit, etc. Oh, and the link to pylib is incorrect. It should be: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py (can't edit, less than 6 chars)

Comment: This is some of the cleanest code I've ever seen. It's a struggle to get people to write code like this for real projects let alone SO answers. Great job.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you define a `main()` function only to be used once rather than putting that functionality in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block? Just curious.

Comment: Force of habit; but it also makes the block of code reuseable.